# Multiple computers will cache old version of included css/php files

Tags: php, css, file, include, dreamweaver

I've been working in Dreamweaver CS4 on two computers, bot by accessing my hosting server (Bluehost) via the FTP feature in DW. Whenever I need to edit a file, I double click the file on my server in the Files Manager and it opens it with the submenu directly under the file name. Here's the example:

[image]

The issue I am having is when I edit includeA.php (which is included in PageA.php) on Computer1 and then go home to edit PageA.php on Computer2. I then save, which then saves over my changes made to includeA.php from Computer1.

Essentially, Is there any way to automatically update included files when opening a file? Or even when I start DW, updating all of my files in a certain directory? I believe I have tried refreshing my working directory before I edited includeA.php, but that did not help...I think... I have set up a test for this and will be testing by my return here (Computer2) tomorrow.

Any ideas? Thanks all!

Comment: DreamWeaver and FTP? Woah, it's like going back into the late 90s. Consider using a version control system - such as Subversion, GIT or Mercurial to version your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a revision control system that solves your problems. [**git?**](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: I agree. Git, Subversion...hell, even CVS. XD Of course Adobe would want you in 'invest' in Contribute and a Contribute server.

Comment: I'm thinkin so too. Probably will start looking into this after this project. For now, I've just turned off the related files submenu. Thanks guys!